# How do I call the first area method from the main method?

Tags: java, math, double, overloading, area

I need the area method that contains the formula for the area of a circle to take in the radius that was found by the other area method that calculated the distance...So one of the area methods calculated the distance/radius then I want that answer to be used in the the radius of the area method for the area of a circle.

```
public class AreaCircle {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    double x1, x2, y1, y2, xc, yc;

    System.out.println("x1: ");
        x1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("x2: ");
        x2 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y1: ");
        y1 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println("y2: ");
        y2 = reader.nextInt();

    double distance = area(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    System.out.println("The radius of the circle is: ");
    System.out.println(distance);

    double answer = area(distance);
    System.out.println("The area of the circle is: ");
    System.out.println(answer);


}

public static double area (double distance) {
    double areaCircle;
    double powRadius;
    double radius = distance;


    powRadius = Math.pow(radius, 2);
    areaCircle = (Math.PI *(powRadius));
    return areaCircle;


}
public static double area (double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2) {
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double dsquared = dx*dx + dy*dy;
    double distance = Math.sqrt (dsquared);
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: That code does exactly what you're saying you want to do. There aren't any errors, and the correct method is being called. What **specifically** is your question?

Comment: What is the exact problem being faced now?

Comment: Do you want to change `public static double area()` to `public static double area(double radius)`?

Comment: Okay sorry the question was very unclear, I just read it over. But I need the area method that contains the formula for the area of a circle to take in the radius that was found by the other area method that calculated the distance...So one of the area methods calculated the distance/radius then I want that answer to be used in the the radius of the area method for the area of a circle. @Jon

Comment: @panzo you should edit your question with these updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is give your `area()` method an input variable that is the radius

Like so:

```
public static double area(double radius) {
    //same as before
    double areaCircle;
    double powRadius;

    powRadius = Math.pow(radius, 2);
    areaCircle = (Math.PI *(powRadius));
    return areaCircle;

}
```

Also rename your other `area()` method. As is, it should be called something like `returnDistance`.

Comment: After I do that how do I call the "returnDistance" method so it inputs that distance as the radius for the formula.

Comment: Do exactly as you are doing in your main method: `double radius = returnDistance(x1, x2, y1, y2);` to have access to the distance. Then call your area function `double outputArea = area(radius);` with this distance to compute and return the area.